# OCaml - Concatenation of Parmap sequences

Tags: list, concatenation, ocaml

Is there any way to concatenate Parmap sequences similar to build-in lists in OCaml ?

Specifically I want to do something that would work like this:

```
let yolo = [1;2;3]
let swag = [4;5;6]

let magic1 = Parmap.L yolo
let magic2 = Parmap.L swag

//below does not work
let result = magic1@magic2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write your own concatenation implementation (even via infix operator with some fancy name, if necessary). Just "destructure" the boxed values, concat them and put the result back to a proper "container":

```
let (|@|) l1 l2 =
  match l1, l2 with
  | Parmap.L l1, Parmap.L l2 -> Parmap.L (l1 @ l2)
  | Parmap.A l1, Parmap.A l2 -> Parmap.A (Array.append l1 l2)
  | _, _ -> failwith "cannot concat oranges to apples"
;;

magic1 |@| magic2;;
- : int Parmap.sequence = Parmap.L [1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're referring to [this parmap](https://opam.ocaml.org/packages/parmap/).

Such an operation, as I understand, would not really profit from parallelization, since you can still only walk through the linked list one element at a time. What about your application prevents you from doing the following?

```ml
let yolo = [1;2;3]
let swag = [4;5;6]

let parseq = Parmap.L (yolo @ swag)
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access (in the specific function at least) to the original lists that the sequences were made of.